Eine der Verwendungen von der Partikel „wohl‟
Mein Grammatikbuch unterscheidet zwischen drei Verwendungen von wohl; die erste ist eine Bestätigung (wie „indeed‟ oder so was), die zweite erscheint als Antwort nach einem Fragewort, um zu implizieren, dass die Frage eine offensichtliche Antwort hat, z.B. Wer hat mein Bier getrunken? Na, wer wohl?
Mit dem dritten wohl (unbetont) habe ich Schwierigkeiten: Es signalisiert „eine vorsichtige Zurückhaltung gegenüber dem Hörer in der Frage‟. Geht es vielleicht um Sarkasmus? Die im Buch gezeigten Beispielen:

Hat er das Buch wohl gelesen? Wann hat er wohl Prüfung?

Außerdem konnte ich keine weitere korrelative Informationen für diese Verwendung.

Die Wortstellung in den beiden Beispielsätzen ist etwas ungewöhnlich. Im zweiten Fall ist eher etwas wie

Wann er wohl Prüfung hat?

üblich. Im ersten Fall würde ich sogar noch mehr umstellen und es formulieren als

Ob er wohl das Buch gelesen hat?

In beiden Fällen drückt "wohl" eine Abschwächung der Erwartung an die Antwort aus. Der Sprecher erwartet keine ganz sichere oder exakte Antwort, eine gut begründete Vermutung genügt auch. Man könnte es mit "Was glaubst Du, ..." umschreiben:

Was glaubst Du, ob er wohl das Buch gelesen hat?
What do you think, did he (ever) read the book?


Was glaubst Du, wann er wohl Prüfung hat?
What do you think, when might his exam be?

Ich würde diese Verwendung von "wohl" unter den Punkt I.4 in DWDS einordnen.

Aus Sicht eines Wieners ist die Wortstellung der beiden Beispielsätze nicht ungewöhnlich.

Der gemeinsame Nenner der Verwendungen ist, daß "wohl" eine menschliche Abschätzung des Wahrheitsgehaltes verlangt, und die Sache nicht vollkommen verstanden oder korrekt sein mag. (1) In "Deutsche sind Schweine." "Das ist wohl wahr" will der Antwortende der Aussage nicht offen widersprechen, ist aber nicht von der Meinung überzeugt. (2) In "Na wer wohl?" steht "wohl" für "Na wer denn deiner Meinung/Einschätzung nach?". (3) In Fragen wie "Hat er das Buch wohl gelesen?" bezieht sich "wohl" auf eine relativ anonyme Meinungsgruppe: "Glauben wir, daß er das Buch gelesen hat?"

Die Antwort "Das ist wohl wahr" zeigt m.E. keinen Widerspruch, sondern, dass man die zuvor getätigte Aussage für wahrscheinlich zutreffend hält (aber nicht alle Informationen hat, um das ohne Zweifel zu bestätigen). Anders hingegen bei einer Antwort wie "ob das wohl wahr ist?". Solche Frage drückt gerade Zweifel an der zuvor getätigten Aussage aus, aber gleichzeitig auch, dass man nicht genügend Informationen besitzt, um diese zu überprüfen (oder Muße, um dagegen zu argumentieren).
